# Disconnecting Google Drive Account

Tags: mac, google-drive

I left my company but forgot to disconnect my google drive from the company email on my macbook air.  Now I'm stuck in the login screen!

I've tried re-installing google drive and removing the following files together:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/
~/Library/Preferences/com.google*
~/Library/Google/
~/Library/Caches/com.google.GoogleDrive
```

All keychain access keys associated with Google.

I've also tried removing all other files that have "google" and "drive" in the filename. I've even tried piping my connection through a remote proxy and setting up a SOCKS connection. **How is Google remembering my work email?**

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean that you are stuck at the log in screen for your email? Or the drive log in on your web browser?

Comment: Oh, you think that google drive is picking up the cache from apple mail?  I think I obliterated the gdrive log.  Could you give me the path to make sure?

Comment: I have the same problem, was this ever resolved?